# Помогите создать древовидные комментарии ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Пытаюсь реализовать древовидные комментарии на сайте с помощью гема - acts-as-commentable-with-threading.

Комментарии отлично создаются и выводятся на сайте, если я захожу на сайт под пользователем (реализовал с помощью гема devise).

Но когда пытаюсь просматривать страницы анонимно, то, естественно, получаю ошибку, что id не может быть вызвано на пустом элемете.

Вот мой контроллер **recipes_controller.rb**:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_chef!, except: [:index, :show]
    def show
        @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
        @comments = @recipe.comment_threads.order('created_at desc')
        @user_who_commented = current_chef
        @new_comment = Comment.build_from(@recipe, @user_who_commented.id, "")
    end
...
```

Вот **comments_controller.rb**:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController  
  before_action :authenticate_chef!

  def create
    commentable = commentable_type.constantize.find(commentable_id)
    @user_who_commented = current_chef
    @comment = Comment.build_from(commentable, @user_who_commented.id, body)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        make_child_comment
        format.html  { redirect_to(:back, :notice => 'Comment was successfully added.') }
      else
        format.html  { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
...
```

**recipe.rb**:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_commentable
...
```

В вьюхе (**recipes/show.html.erb**) вставляю такой рендер:

```
<%= render partial: "comments/template", locals: {commentable: @recipe, new_comment: @comment} %>
```

Думаю, что, возможно, нужно в контроллере создать что-то наподобие конструкции if ... else для тех, кто просто просматривает сайт, ведь по умолчанию на данный момент в методе show задано значение current_chef, из-за чего и ошибка.

Answer (score 3):

Сделайте if else или unless во вьюхе recipes/show.html.erb  а точнее в partial'е "comments/template"
что то вроде

```
<% if current_user_id? %>
 заданное значение current_chef
<% else %>
  Войдите чтобы ответить
<% end %>
```

Может это поможет